# how to display whether a record has a two-field matchin across two tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, left-join, match

I'm using `MySQL 5.1` and I'm sitting over a query, which I can't get to display what I need.

I have two tables.

```
#table 1 - auth tokens
sellerId 
zip
token

#table 2 - authenticated attempts
sellerId
buyerId
buyer_zip
buyer_submitted_token
```

The 2nd table includes all attempts (successful or not) for authentication.

I now want to display all records from table 1 (submitted zip & tokens) together with information on whether an authentication with this combination was successfull or not (success being `zip matches buyer_zip` and `token matches buyer_submitted_token`).

Problem is I can't get it to work.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT z.buyer_id,
   z.seller_id
   z.buyer_submitted_token
   z.buyer_zip
   k.token,
   k.zip

 FROM table_1 AS z

 LEFT JOIN table_2 AS k
    ON k.buyer_id= "12345"
    AND k.zip = z.buyer_zip
    AND k.token = z.buyer_submitted_token

 WHERE z.seller_id =  "12345"
 LIMIT 0, 50
```

This returns all records for a seller from table_1, which is ok. What I want to add is whether the combinations available have been successfully used = `z.buyer_zip` and `z.buyer_submitted_token` match a record in table 2.

**Question:**
How do I check in MySQL if a record with field values A and B has a matching record in another table?

Answer (score 0):

You might have an issue here:

```
ON k.buyer_id= "12345"
```

On should links fields together in my understanding

```
ON k.sellerId = z. sellerId
```